# ethereum POS new burned algorithm

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

The burn: At an average gas price of at least 16 gwei, at least 1,600 ETH is burned every day (https://ethereum.org/en/upgrades/merge/issuance/)

1-Where does “at least 16 gwei” come from ? Is there any calculation or is this assumption?

2-Where does “at least 1,600 ETH is burned every day” come from? Is this **Consensus layer issuance’s result, isnt it?

3- What is the relationship between fee and burned amount ?Is there any equation?
Because I see for 16 gwei situation will result in burning 1600 ETH daily and 20 gwei will result in burning 2000 ETH daily (https://ultrasound.money/ )

4- What is the target of Total annual issuance rate in 2022 and 2023?

[ispanyolca](https://www.ispanyol.com/)

Answer (score 0):

1. At least 1600 ETH/day comes from the PoS issuance rate at the time of the update of the article https://ethereum.org/en/upgrades/merge/issuance/. This is both a calculation and an assumption.
2. See above. This is the consensus layer issuance.
3. The relationship between fee and burned amount is that every time a transaction on Ethereum is executed, a portion of the transaction fee is burnt in ETH.
4. Target of total annual issuance rate in 2022 (post-merge) and 2023 is ~0.5%. (https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ethereum-deflationary-currency-post-merge-120-17-2022-arslanian)